# Excel: Combine data from 2 tables

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to achieve something I believe will be quite simple but just can't figure out on my own.

What I'm trying to achieve is a full list of product IDs + Filenames. All filenames are the same for each product ID.

Table 1: Product ID's
Table 2: File Names
Goal: Create a record for each product ID + Filename combination

Thanks in advance.

[image: Prodcut ID]
[image: Filenames]
[image: Goal]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file name table is loaded into PowerQuery and the table is named **File_names_table**, then

In the in the **Product ID table**, add column .. custom column ...  and use formula:

```
= File_names_table
```

Then click the arrows atop the Custom column and expand to new rows

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Product_ID_Table"]}[Content],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Custom", each File_names_table),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"File names"}, {"File names"})
in #"Expanded Custom"
```